# Ubuntu 18.04 which screen recorder allows muted speakers

Tags: desktop-recording

Ubuntu 18.04 MATE.

I am looking for a screen recorder that records video and audio, but will allow me to record when the screen brightness is turned down, and the volume is also turned down. I have tried Simple Screen Recorder. When I turn the brightness down it still records the video as if the brightness was set to high. This is what I wanted. However, if I try to turn the sound down this is reflected in the recording and I do not hear anything. So my aim is to be able to record the screen with both the screen and the audio completely turned down.